# Convert object to use spread operator?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, object, redux

I have a case in redux reducers and I used an object.assign to take a copy of my state, and I want to transform it to new syntax spread operator"...state", how can I make it,

Without making a mutation!

```
case INCREASE_QUANTITY: {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        cart: state.cart.map(item => {
          if (item.product.id === action.productInfo.product.id) {
            return Object.assign({}, item, {
              quantity: action.quantity + 1,
            });
          }
          return item;
        }),
      });
    }
```

Comment: Note: `...` isn't an operator. It can't be: Operators have a single result value (like functions do). `...` (both when used as spread and rest) is primary syntax. Not that it *really* matters :-) ... but that's why they can only be used in some places and not others.

Comment: Hmm, what's the place we can't use it? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: `a = b + ...data` for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open an object literal, start with `...state` to spread that out into the new object, and follow it with the `cart` property (and the same concept for the inner one):

```
case INCREASE_QUANTITY: {
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: state.cart.map(item => {
      if (item.product.id === action.productInfo.product.id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          quantity: action.quantity + 1,
        };
      }
      return item;
    }),
  };
}
```

By doing it in that order, you ensure that `cart` (or `quantity` for the inner one) overrides the property from the spread. Later properties in in object literals "win" over earlier ones.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign({}, item, { quantity: action.quantity + 1 });`
becomes
`{ ...item, quantity: action.quantity + 1 }`

```
case INCREASE_QUANTITY : {
    return {
        ...state,
        cart : state.cart.map(item => {
            if (item.product.id === action.productInfo.product.id) {
                return {
                    ...item,
                    quantity: action.quantity + 1
                }
            }
            return item;
        })
    };
}
```